# TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating'_reactNative.route.params) React Navigation 5.0

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

**I know there are other questions from S.O. that were similar to my issue but they did not work for me.**

I am trying to send variables from Home screen to another Follow screen. However I am getting the error:

**TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating'_reactNative.route.params)**

I am not sure if this has to do with how I wrote my code for passing parameters to routes in React Navigation 5.0. But I looked at the documentation and the code looked fine to me.

Here is my code:

Home.JS

```js
import { StatusBar } from 'expo-status-bar';
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, Button, navigation } from 'react-native';
import Follow from './Follow';

export default class Home extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            followRequest: ['John', 'Jane', 'Ram', 'Janice'],
            following: ['Hitesh']
        };
    }

    doFollow = index => {
        const { followRequest, following } = this.state;

        const followNew = followRequest.splice(index, 1);

        following.push(followNew)

        this.setState({
            followRequest,
            following
        });
    };

    render() {

        console.log(this.props.navigation)

    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <Text>You are following {this.state.following.length}</Text>
            <Text>You have {this.state.followRequest.length} follow requests</Text>
            <Button
                title='Follow Page'
                onPress={() => {

                    this.props.navigation.navigate('Follow', {
                        
                        followRequest: this.state.followRequest,
                        following: this.state.following,
                        doFollow: this.doFollow()

                    });
                }}
            />
        </View>
            );
    }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
});
```

Follow.JS

```js
import { StatusBar } from 'expo-status-bar';
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, Button, TouchableOpacityBase, route, navigation} from 'react-native';


export default class Follow extends React.Component {


    render() {

        const { followRequest }  = route.params;
        const { doFollow }  = route.params;

    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>

            <Text>followRequest: {JSON.stringify(followRequest)}</Text>   
          
        <Button
                title='Home Page'
                onPress={() => {
                    this.props.navigation.navigate('Home')
                } }
            />
        </View>
            );
    }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are importing `route` and `navigation` from 'react-native'.
They should be access as props using `this.props`.

```js
import { StatusBar } from 'expo-status-bar';
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, Button, TouchableOpacityBase } from 'react-native';


export default class Follow extends React.Component {


    render() {

        const { followRequest }  = this.props.route.params;
        const { doFollow }  = this.props.route.params;

    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>

            <Text>followRequest: {JSON.stringify(followRequest)}</Text>   
          
        <Button
                title='Home Page'
                onPress={() => {
                    this.props.navigation.navigate('Home')
                } }
            />
        </View>
            );
    }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
});
```